# How to correctly swap std::function multiple times?

Tags: c++, std-function

The code below is trying to swap some std::function variables but fails. Especially `next_` and `read_` are not *accepting* other values as initialised to.

How can this functor be changed in a way that `next_` is swapped with `index_`, `path_` and `empty_` as well as `read_` and `next`? The goal is to went through all private methods.

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Envs {
public:
    Envs()
      : empty_(std::bind(&Envs::empty,this,std::placeholders::_1))
      , path_(std::bind(&Envs::path,this,std::placeholders::_1))
      , index_(std::bind(&Envs::index,this,std::placeholders::_1))
      , next_(path_)
      , read_(index_) {
    }
    void operator()(std::string const & _arg) {
        read_(_arg);
        std::swap(next_,read_);
    }
private:
    void empty(std::string const & _empty) {
        std::cout << "empty: " <<_empty << "\n";
    }
    void path(std::string const & _path) {
        std::cout << "path: " << _path << "\n";
        std::swap(next_,empty_);
    }
    void index(std::string const & _index) {
        std::cout << "index: " <<_index << "\n";
        std::swap(next_,path_);
    }
    std::function<void(std::string const &)> empty_;
    std::function<void(std::string const &)> path_;
    std::function<void(std::string const &)> index_;
    std::function<void(std::string const &)> next_;
    std::function<void(std::string const &)> read_;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> args = {"A","B","C"};
    Envs envs;
    std::for_each(args.begin(),args.end(),envs);
}
```

Comment: Please describe what the output of the program is and what you expect it to be and why.

Comment: It compiles with g++ version 5.3.1. What's exactly the problem?

Comment: the output shall be like `index: A path: B empty: C`. The problem is that std:swap does not swap inside private methods at all.

Comment: Check here, with C++14: https://ideone.com/SAsgyF seems to work Just Fine (famous last words); if you take "producing the desired output" as an indication that your problem does not occur.

Comment: The output of https://ideone.com/SAsgyF looks like `index: A path: B index: C`. I don't know why it's not `index: A path: B empty: C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in the way you are passing your `envs` object to `std::for_each` function. Because it gets copied, `this` pointer in `bind` object is also copied, which basically means you are operating on methods in other object.

Replacing:

```
Envs envs;
std::for_each(args.begin(),args.end(),envs);
```

With:

```
std::for_each(args.begin(),args.end(), Envs());
```

Should help.